# Ionic 3 google maps link generated in the head

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm working on an offline app with ionic version 3 but something strange always happens when i run "ionic cordova run android"

In the index.html in head it generates this :

```
  <!-- cordova.js required for cordova apps (remove if not needed) -->
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=xxx"></script>
  <script src="cordova.js"></script>
```

I removed all the plugins and modules for gps and maps
this is my package.json file:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.11",
    "@ionic-native/aes-256": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/android-permissions": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/app-update": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/app-version": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/barcode-scanner": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/bluetooth-serial": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "~4.18.0",
    "@ionic-native/device": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/diagnostic": "^4.19.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "^2.2.0",
    "cordova-android": "8.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-advanced-http": "^2.1.1",
    "cordova-plugin-aes256-encryption": "^1.2.2",
    "cordova-plugin-android-permissions": "^1.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-app-update": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-app-version": "^0.1.9",
    "cordova-plugin-appversion": "^1.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-bluetooth-serial": "0.4.7",
    "cordova-plugin-dbcopy": "^2.1.2",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-email-composer": "^0.9.2",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "^6.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.1.3",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^2.5.1",
    "cordova-plugin-network-information": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-permission": "0.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.3",
    "cordova-plugin-uid": "^1.3.0",
    "cordova-plugin-uniquedeviceid": "^1.3.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.4",
    "cordova-plugin-x-toast": "^2.7.2",
    "cordova-sqlite-storage": "^3.2.1",
    "cordova.plugins.diagnostic": "^4.0.12",
    "ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.5.11",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "ts-md5": "^1.2.4",
    "zone.js": "0.8.26"
  },
```

I don't need maps anyways so any help would be appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

There is probably still plugins defined in your Cordova config.xml file.

Or alternatively remove the plugins with Cordova command

```
cordova plugin remove <plugin>
```

or

```
cordova plugin rm <plugin>
```

Comment: just checked and everthing seems to be fine